# Trash Filing System

Tags: bash, file-system, cli

This is a script (function) to be added to a bashrc. The purpose is to not actually remove files, but rather to send them to a trash folder for safe keeping. I was tired of deleting important files. Because files may have the same name, I chose to create subdirectories with the date and file name on them, for easy access and to prevent conflicts.

Thoughts? Improvements I could make? This is my first BASH script function, and I'd love to make it a standard part of my computers, so I want to make it good first!

```
function rm { 
    PREFIX="~/.Trash";
    for FILE in "$@" ; do 
        STARDATE=`date +%Y%m%d-%H%M`;
        PLACE="${STARDATE}-${FILE}" ; 
        mkdir -p "${PREFIX}/${PLACE}"; 
        mv $FILE $PREFIX/$PLACE/$FILE ; 
        echo "${FILE} moved to ${PREFIX}/${PLACE}" ; 
    done
}
```

Comment: Does this work if the file name has spaces in it? I suspect it doesn't, since `$PREFIX/$PLACE/$FILE` is not quoted. Also, why do you use `${foo}` instead of just `$foo`?

Comment: What operating system? Have you also considered LVM snapshots (Linux) or ZFS snapshots (BSD/Solaris) or Time Machine backups (Mac OS)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interesting idea! I propose to rewrite the script this way:

```
rm() { 
    TRASH=~/.Trash
    for FILE; do
        DATE=$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M)
        TARGETDIR="$TRASH/$DATE-$FILE"
        mkdir -p "$TARGETDIR"
        mv -v "$FILE" "$TARGETDIR/"
    done
}
```

What I changed and why:

- `for i; do` is equivalent to `for i in "$@"; do` but shorter
- In `PREFIX="~/.Trash"`, the `~` does NOT expand to your home directory, so I believe this is a bug. And since there's nothing to quote in `.Trash` either, you can just write `PREFIX=~/.Trash` without any quoting
- Instead of an `echo` after the `mv`, you can use the `-v` flag to make `mv` more verbose and speak for itself
- Correctly quoted everywhere it's necessary
- Changed the deprecated `` `cmd` `` style command substitution to the new recommended `$(cmd)` style
- Renamed variables to be more intuitive, though I know this is subjective:

  - PREFIX to TRASH, to be more specific and clear
  - STARDATE to DATE, because I don't know what is "STAR" and DATE alone is already pretty clear
  - combined PREFIX + PLACE to TARGETDIR to reduce duplication
- Changed `function rm {` to `rm() {`, because this seems to be the preferred way to declare functions in bash
- Removed all the trailing `;`, you don't need them
- Use `$VARNAME` instead of `${VARNAME}`, because I find that easier to read, but do as you like

Personally I would rename `rm()` to `trash()`,
because most of the time I certainly don't want to backup everything,
especially when deleting directories.
`trash` also seems intuitive.

By the way, this is a great site to check your Bash scripts for common mistakes:

http://www.shellcheck.net/#

Answer (score 4):

You should realize that this is not a drop-in replacement for `/bin/rm`. For example, this function won't handle options such as `-f` correctly.

You double-quoted several variable expansions, but you must make it a religious habit to always double-quote *all* such expansions. Otherwise, special characters in filenames will break your script in nasty ways.

Error handling is poor. You'll echo a confirmation even when `mv` fails. Therefore, you should join commands nontrivial with semicolons, but with `&&`.  Also, errors should go to standard error instead of standard out, so use `echo "…" >&2`.